# setting the angle of a b2revolutejoint

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

From what I have read, in Box2d, you get the angle of a revolute joint with the GetJointAngle function, but when trying to set the angle the member m_referenceAngle is protected. Can the angle not be programmatically set?

I found that I can apply the angle from one joint to another body as:

float FirstAngle = firstArmJoint->GetJointAngle();
secondArmBody->SetTransform(b2Vec2((750.0/PTM_RATIO),(520.0f+100)/PTM_RATIO),hourAngle);

I put this in ccTouchesMoved so that when the user drags the first object (from which FirstAngle is retrieved) the second object (secondArmBody) is also moved.

What happens is that the second body rotates at the top of the image and not at the anchor point.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found that I could apply the angle to the B2body that the joint was related to as:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetTransform()` can be used to set the position and rotation of a body. This happens completely independently of any joints on the body. For example, if you want to make sure a body is perfectly upright at a given moment, you can call

```
body->SetTransForm(body->GetPosition(), 0);
```

passing 0 as the angle value (upright). I've never tried this for a body with a joint on it, but I doubt it would work properly.

When I ran into the problem of having to make a revolutejoint point at a certain angle, I solved it by enabling motor on the joint and adjusting the motor speed until the angle matched the one I wanted. This simulates realistic motion of the joint. Example:

### Creating the joint

```
b2RevoluteJointDef armJointDef;
armJointDef.Initialize(body1, body2,
    b2Vec2(body1->GetPosition().x,
    ((body1->GetPosition().y/PTM_RATIO));
armJointDef.enableMotor = true;
armJointDef.enableLimit = true;
armJointDef.motorSpeed = 0.0f;
armJointDef.maxMotorTorque = 10000.0f;
armJointDef.lowerAngle = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lowerArmAngle);
armJointDef.upperAngle = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(upperArmAngle);
_world->CreateJoint(&armJointDef);
```

### Pointing the joint

```
float targetAngle = SOME_ANGLE;
b2JointEdge *j = body->GetJointList();
b2RevoluteJoint *r = (b2RevoluteJoint *)j->joint;
if(r->GetAngle() > targetAngle){
    r->SetMotorSpeed(-1);
} else { r->SetMotorSpeed(1); }
```

Basically, you see what side of the current angle the target angle is on, and then set the motor speed to move the joint in the correct direction. Hope that helps!

http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

Comment: yes, I can use that (point the joint) to move the second object in the direction that I move the first object, but it just causes the object to spin in that direction and does not match the speed or stops spinning when I release the first object